# Appcelerator Android Ti.Cloudpush start up woes

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, genymotion, appcelerator-titanium

Having a small issue running an app on Genymotion. I'm currently just finishing up the UI for the Green Guy and have come across a problem launching when I activate the cloud push module.

The error I am getting is below.

```
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [36,275] Sending event: exception on  thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.appcelerator.aps.PushBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: PushType is NONE!; Titanium 5.1.2,2015/12/16 19:00,ca822b2
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.appcelerator.aps.PushBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: PushType is NONE!
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: PushType is NONE!
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.appcelerator.aps.CCPushService.ifEnabled(CCPushService.java:256)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.appcelerator.aps.PushBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(PushBroadcastReceiver.java:59)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   ... 10 more
```

Im running SDK 5.1.2GA and have the relevant XML properties in my tiapp.xml file. I have set up the keys in Google Developer console and entered those details into the Appcelerator Platform web portal.

I'm kind of stuck with this. Is this because Im running on an emulator? Or am I missing something and just having another developer moment.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: Google Cloud Push requires that Google Play Services be installed on the device/emulator. I am not sure if Genymotion has that or not. Can you try it in the Google API emulator provided by Google and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion emulators [do not come with Google Apps](https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#google-apps-missing) requires for push notifications (via GCM).

Please Google to learn how to install Google Apps on Genymotion emulators, or simply use an Android Emulator (AVD). The most recent ones are actually really fast.

See [this blog post](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/titanium-5-2-0-google-maps-streetview-panorama/#emulator) as well.